# GET report with Different Where condition

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, database

I have a table with fields

```
TPI
CLICKS
IMPRESSION
CLASSIFY
```

I need to get 3 result

```
1st) SUM(CLICKS)/SUM(IMPRESSION) * 100 GROUP BY TPI
2nd) SUM(IMPRESSION) WHERE CLASSIFY = "XYZ" GROUP BY TPI
3rd) SUM(IMPRESSION) WHERE CLASSIFY = "ABC" GROUP BY TPI
```

Desired OP

```
TPI 1st_data 2nd_data 3rd_data
```

WHERE TPI is unique in output 
Can I achive this in single query ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional aggregation should work for you. Use a `CASE` in the `sum()`'s argument to only use the value `impression` when your condition on `classify` is satisfied.

```
SELECT tpi,
       sum(clicks) / sum(impression) * 100 1st_data,
       sum(CASE classify
             WHEN 'XYZ'
               THEN impression
             ELSE
               0
           END) 2nd_data,
       sum(CASE classify
             WHEN 'ABC'
               THEN impression
             ELSE
               0
           END) 3rd_data
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY tpi;
```